# Batch Create folders based first part filename, move files into that folder

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

Looking through the solution here can't seem find precisely what looking for or can't quite see how I modify existing scripts. I have a windows fileserver. I have documents stored in a directory structure, Year, Month, Week 01/02 etc. The filenames are in the format 0053910001.1.D799D for example. The first part is a client identifier, there maybe many files with the same identifier so 0053910001.2.D444D,0053910001.3.D584D etc. I need a bat file script that will go through the directory and create a separate directory named as the client identifier 0053910001 and then copy all the files with that identifier into that directory.

Thanks.

Paul,

Answer (score 0):

i need some more informations... 
is the directory structure like "2014, 11, 01\0053910001.1.D799D" or something like
"2014\11\01\0053910001.1.D799D"?

means "D799D" the extension?

does the client identifier always contain 10 digits/letters?

do you know if there are duplicate filenames to be aware of?

where should the target-folder be created?

Kind regards

---

Edit:

Save this to a File (e.g. "Cleanup.cmd") direct in Drive H:

```
@ECHO OFF
  IF NOT EXIST "Clients" MD "Clients"
  FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=." %%A IN ('DIR 2014\* /s /b /a:-d') DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "Clients\%%~nA" MD "Clients\%%~nA"
    MOVE "%%~A.%%~B" "Clients\%%~nA"
  )
```

Description:

> FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=." %%A IN ('DIR 2014* /s /b /a:-d') DO (

Will Search for all files in the directory "2014" and all subdirs

> IF NOT EXIST "%%~nA" MD "%%~nA"

Will create a Folder based on the filename (w/o extension), so that folder will be for example "053920001" in the root-directory H:

> MOVE "%%~A.%%~B" "%%~dA\%%~nA"

Will move the files in the above created directory.

---

for testing you can replace "move" with "copy", so that all the sourcefiles will stay at their location.

Edited to fit the need of placing files and folders in subdir "clients"

Comment: Directory structure would be like

Comment: Directory structure would be like h:\2014\March\Week01\, depending on how many weeks in month Week01, Week02 etc. In each week directory are the individual files 0053910001.1.D799D some will have same client identifier some different. I need to sort files into separate folders named as client identifier. So all files that start 0053910001 would be placed in folder called 0053910001.

Comment: And at which path do you want to have the target folder to be created?

Comment: Ok looking at it, overcomplicating the thing. Not great task to drag and drop all files into single directory say YEAR. Then get a batch file to sort all files that relate to same client identifier into a folder of the same name ie 0053910001.

Comment: I would have all folder containing the data in c:\year so say create client folders in c:\clients

Comment: Ok, ran this works perfectly, BIG thanks for this. All I need to do now is produce a text CSV file mapping the client identifier to the client name like: 0020080008, Mr and Mrs Jones
0020080009, Matrix Ltd
0020080010, Mr John Kelly, then create a batch to rename the folders with the client name.

Comment: You're welcome - i'm glad i could help you. - 
It would be very nice if you mark my code as answer :)

Comment: Just a little hint: 
If you open a command prompt in the folder, that is containing all your client-identifier-folders, and type `DIR /a:d /b >>Folders.txt` it will create a txt file, with all foldernames listed. This you can copy easy to any other program you like to create your csv. :)

Comment: Ok thanks BaBa. I tried mark answer, but appears I need 'reputation' of at least 15. Being a new user no reputation..